# Live Append Form Input to HTML String

Tags: jquery, forms, input, append

I would like to get a header for question two (and other subsequent questions) of my form to update based on what is entered in question one's text input immediately after it is entered (but before it is sent), but despite trying several solutions SO has shown me I haven't managed. Any help much appreciated! Here's my latest iteration:

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dexter" name="name" style="background-color:#DFECF5;" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your pet's name.">...

<h3>What Breed is<div id="namer"></div></h3>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<input name="name" type="text"/>').appendTo("div.namer");
});
```

***EDIT***

I have since learned JS Angular and it sorted this out for me in seconds :)

```
<div ng-app="">

<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p>You wrote: {{ name }}</p> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
      <input type="text" class="form-control dexter" placeholder="Dexter" name="name" style="background-color:#DFECF5;" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your pet's name."/>

        <h3>What Breed is <div class="namer"></div></h3>
         <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dexter").blur(function(){
var dextervalue=$(".dexter").val();
$(".breed").remove();
$('<input name="name" class="breed" type="text" value"'+dextervalue+'"/>').appendTo("div.namer");
$(".breed").val(dextervalue);
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cq3moa34/

Comment: @user3190635 check it and let me know

Comment: Thanks for the response - I put this in but it seems to be coming up as a input itself now. http://tinypic.com/r/15hzzlv/8

Comment: What do want exactly? where that field need to add?

Comment: I was wondering if it could appear as a regular word in the header after it was typed into the box (and changing should what is typed in the box changes)? I wasn't sure if this was possible with jQuery...

Comment: So the "name" input would automatically parse into the namer div (whilst looking like a regular piece of the title).

Comment: i think you want if first textfield what type value is load in next "What breed is" textfield and the second textfield  appear when the firstfield is typed?

Comment: Correct. "What breed is" can already be typed and then the breed appears after the first text box is completed. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: My answer is correct means support and accept my answer.